# Why doesn't PHP populate $_POST with the passed parameters?

Tags: php, node.js, webserver, cgi

I write a simple web server in JavaScript with NodeJS. I have the problem, that PHP doesn't populate $_POST with the passed parameters. What I already achieved is, that $_GET is populated with the passed parameters.

```
process.env["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"] = "CGI/1.1";
process.env["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = path.resolve(resource);
process.env["REQUEST_METHOD"] = request[0];
process.env["REDIRECT_STATUS"] = 200;
process.env["QUERY_STRING"] = queryString;
process.env["CONTENT_LENGTH"] = queryString.length;
process.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

content = execSync(phpPath +"php-cgi", process.env);
```

But print_r($_POST) gives me Array ( ). If I use GET it works and the parameters are in $_GET. My assumption is, that the problem is somewhere in the environment variables. queryString.length is the size of the POST parameters given by the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I had to pipe the query string as stdin input for php-cgi:

```
content = execSync(phpPath +"php-cgi", { env: process.env, input: queryString });
```

This only works with POST that's why I check for POST and GET now and set the method accordingly